# Does this sentence imply that anthocyanin contains iron?

Tags: meaning

I am watching an SBS TV program about food and cooking and it shows this:

[image: screenshot]

As I understand it, it seems to say that the red color of the strawberry
is from [anthocyanin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthocyanin) which contains large quantities of iron healthy for children. I did not really know what anthocyanin is and had to look it up. But I was not able to find any info about it actually containing iron.

Is this a mistake of the program or have I misunderstood something? I read the first word of the second line as 철분 (iron). It could also be 절분 because I am not sure whether the heart-shaped decoration belongs to the writing itself, but 절분 does not seem to make sense here.

Comment: You've understood the caption perfectly; it's just that the caption is scientifically incorrect. Well done!

Comment: @Jihyung Kang Thanks. I later found out that anthocyanin can bond with iron or magnesium atoms to form something called a "chelate" ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Delphinidin_iron_complex.svg)). So the program might be correct after all. Sorry for bringing up a topic more suitable for another stack exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is implied so.
Straberry's red color / HAS (anthocyanin / WITH iron / GOOD FOR children)

So, it is implied that anthocyanin contains iron.

Oh well... it's well known to native Koreans that such TV shows are merely another type of paid advertisements. Don't trust everything they say. You would find it funny when you find out they say APPLE IS GOOD for blah blah one day, but APPLE IS DANGEROUS for blah blah another day. It depends on what they sell on other shopping channels at the same time. lol.

Companies broadcast their products on shopping channels and pay to give favorable information for their product on other TV shows broadcasting at the same time so that people could switch channels and buy it right away.

TV is Advertisement. NOT information these days.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question but I do appreciate your answer. For sure it's difficult to find unbiased and scientific info on TV these days.

Answer (score 0):

You understood it correctly the first time. The heart shaped decoration belongs to the letter, 철, and it  means iron. You were correct.

Answer (score 0):

'딸기의 붉은색 안토시아닌 성분은 철분이 많아 성장기 아이들에게 좋습니다'

= 'The red anthocyanin component of strawberries is high in iron, so it is good for growing children'

The expression that you understand that anthocyanins are high in iron is correct.

The heart shape is only part of the font.